# Statistical analysis of paired count data

Tags: r, anova, count-data, poisson-regression, paired-data

I have conducted an experiment where groups of animals were allowed to select between different substrates.
I had a tank with four different substrates (increasing in complexity from one side of the tank to the other). 100 animals was then evenly distributed into the tank and kept there undisturbed for 24 hours. After 24 hours the number of individuals found in each substrate was counted. This experiment was repeated five times in order to eliminate the chance that the distribution was due to chance.

Example showing (hypothetical) number of animals found in each substrate at each trial:

[image]

I want to test if there is a higher preference for a specific substrate, but not sure which type of statistical test I should run on this data. Can I use a Poisson-regression on this data, when the response in each trial is a paired value (I.e. for instance that the number of individuals found in A, B, and C will automatically determine the number of animals found in D). Or maybe other statistical tests will be more appropriate..
Any help greatly appreciated!

Edit: Updated information in questions.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you see that when the distance between points of these variables are constant and when there is a true point of zero, count data are treated as interval/ratio variables and analyzed with ANOVA or OLS. Count outcome variables are sometimes log-transformed and analyzed using OLS. When the data is positively skewed you can use a Poisson regression with a glm function to analyze the data. You can estimate the deviance (goodness) of fit to a Poisson distribution and use a Poisson regression. See Cameron, A. C. and Trivedi, P. K. 2009. Microeconometrics Using Stata. College Station, TX: Stata Press. and Nussbaum, E. M., Elsadat, S., & Khago, A. H. (2008). Best practices in analyzing count data: Poisson regression. Best practices in quantitative methods, 306-323.